# Can't read file after writing it to temp folder in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, shapefile, memorystream

In my scenario, I have an use case where I must received a compressed file, do some validations and then find a specific file within the archive that I'll have to handle through a third-party library. I'm having some trouble getting such library to read the file though. This is what I came up with so far:

```
public async Task ShapeIt(ZipArchive archive)
{
    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if (Path.GetExtension(entry.FullName).Equals(".shp"))
        {
            var stream = entry.Open();
            using var ms = new MemoryStream();
            await stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            var fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
            try
            {
                using var fileStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, 
                    FileShare.ReadWrite);

                var bytes = new byte[ms.Length];
                ms.Read(bytes, 0, (int)ms.Length);
                fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                fileStream.Flush();
                fileStream.Close();

                var featureSource = new ShapeFileFeatureSource(fileName); // Class from 3rd-party
                featureSource.Open();
                // Do my stuff with the shapefile
            }
            finally
            {
                File.Delete(fileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Take notice that I'm using the "old way" of copying streams as `Stream.CopyTo` and `Stream.CopyToAsync` were creating empty files, explicitly calling `fileStream.Close()` looks like the only way to get the bytes into the file somehow, but that's beyond my point. Regardless, after *closing the stream*, upon calling `featureSource.Open()` my application throws

```
"The process cannot access the file 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpE926.tmp' because it is
being used by another process."
```

`tmpE926.tmp` being different every time, obviously. Also take notice that I'm creating a file because the constructor for `ShapeFileFeatureSource` demands not a stream, not a byte array, but a path.

A much shorter implementation

```
public async Task ShapeIt(ZipArchive archive)
{
    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        try
        {
            entry.ExtractToFile(tempFile, true);

            if (Path.GetExtension(entry.FullName).Equals(".shp"))
            {
                var featureSource = new ShapeFileFeatureSource(tempFile);
                featureSource.Open();
                var type = featureSource.GetShapeFileType();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            File.Delete(tempFile);
        }
    }
}
```

will actually amount to the same error. I honestly don't think the problem lies within this library, but rather I'm the one screwing it up somehow. Does anyone have any ideas or should I contact the vendor's (unresponsive) tech support?

Edit: Just in case, this is such library `Install-Package ThinkGeo.UI.WebApi` but you have to subscribe to evaluate in order to use it.

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner that might be watching that folder?

Comment: what is the name of the package you are using? i can't find it for .net core, is it public?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I ran some more tests and I think it is a problem with the third-party library. Their tech support reached back to me, I have some more tools at my disposal now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code morphed for a couple of days until I reached out to tech support, they tinkered with it a bit and came up with this:

```
public async Task ProcessFile(IFormFile file)
{
    if (!Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).Equals(".zip"))
        throw new System.Exception("File should be compressed in '.zip' format");

    var filePaths = new List<string>();

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);

        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Read, false))
        {

            var replaceList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                var tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();

                string key = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(entry.FullName);

                string value = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempPath);

                if (replaceList.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    value = replaceList[key];
                }
                else
                {
                    replaceList.Add(key, value);
                }

                string unzippedPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(tempPath), value + Path.GetExtension(entry.FullName));

                entry.ExtractToFile(unzippedPath, true);
                filePaths.Add(unzippedPath);
            }

            foreach (var unzippedPath in filePaths)
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(unzippedPath).Equals(".shp"))
                {
                    // Successfully doing third-party library stuff
                }
            }

            foreach (var unzippedPath in filePaths)
            {
                if (File.Exists(unzippedPath))
                {
                    File.Delete(unzippedPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works. I'm happy.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find package for .NET Core with such classes, so I reproduced it through .NET Framework Nuget package. My answer mostly demonstrates how to deal with streams. It would be hard to tell what is wrong with your code, without having access to library you have

```
using DotSpatial.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\jjjjjjjjjjjj\Downloads\1270055001_mb_2011_vic_shape.zip"))
            using (var zipFile = new ZipArchive(fs))
            {
                foreach (var entry in zipFile.Entries)
                {
                    if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".shp"))
                    {
                        var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
                        try
                        {
                            using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                            using (var newFileStream = File.OpenWrite(tempFile))
                            {
                                entryStream.CopyTo(newFileStream);
                            }
                            var featureSource = ShapefileFeatureSource.Open(tempFile);
                            var type = featureSource.ShapeType;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            File.Delete(tempFile);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPD: installed trial version of ThinkGeo library, instead of unauthorized exception it gives me `FileNotFoundException` with given stacktrace

```
at ThinkGeo.Core.ValidatorHelper.CheckFileIsExist(String pathFilename)
at ThinkGeo.Core.ShapeFileIndex.xh8=(FileAccess readWriteMode)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Are we supposed to have index?
at ThinkGeo.Core.ShapeFile.xh8=(FileAccess readWriteMode)
at ThinkGeo.Core.ShapeFileFeatureSource.WjE=()
at ThinkGeo.Core.ShapeFileFeatureSource.OpenCore()
at ThinkGeo.Core.FeatureSource.Open()
at ConsoleApp20.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
C:\Users\jjjjjjjjjjjj\source\repos\ConsoleApp20\ConsoleApp20\Program.cs:line 45
```

`ShapeFileIndex` ? So I thought I should dig into this way

```
var featureSource = new ShapeFileFeatureSource(tempFile);
featureSource.RequireIndex = false; // no luck
featureSource.Open();
```

I tried to find any reference to the idx file it wants, it has property `IndexFilePathName`, but unfortunately, I am out of luck. (Also tried different folder, so it is not 'Temp' folder issue)
[image]

Comment: If you're still interested, I added the library to the original question

Comment: @makoshichi posted an update, but could not solve it myself. I think you are right about tech support request

Comment: Hey, tech support got it to work. You can check my answer if you'd like

Comment: Weirdly enough, that's a different problem and I know its fix, one should call `ShapeFileFeatureLayer.BuildIndexFile(unzippedPath);` before trying to open the file, but only if an idx file is not present already.